# loading scripts via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Consider the following example.

```
    $.ajax({
        url:      ajaxViewModelUrl,
        dataType: 'script'
    }).done(function(){
      self.hideLoading();
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.error('Satus: ' + textStatus);
      console.error('Error: ' + errorThrown);
    });
```

Lets assume that the script located at `ajaxViewModelUrl` throws an error when attempting to be loaded.

You instantly hit the `.fail` and get an error like:

```
ddc_widget.js:573 Satus: parsererror
ddc_widget.js:574 Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
```

- ddc_widget is the file thats attempting to load the file via ajax.

**So, my question is, how do I get it to tell me what line this particular error appeared on in the file thats attempting to be loaded via ajax?**

*if thats possible at all*

Comment: If i undesrtand you question correctly, the error appears to be located in the line 574.

Comment: No you don't. The error appears on 547 of the ddc_widget file that contains the Ajax call. The actual error is in the file being loaded, I wanna know the line of the error in the file being loaded. If possible

Comment: Try [`Error.prototype.lineNumber`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/lineNumber).

Comment: try `errorThrown.error.stack` Idea came from an article I read yesterday. http://www.sitepoint.com/proper-error-handling-javascript/

Comment: `Error.prototype.lineNumber` and `errorThrown.error.stack` do not work. apparently you cannot call stack on an undefined and same with lineNumber @Shashank

Comment: I guess the type of `errorThrown` is a String according to jq docs. That really sucks.